# How can I pass multiple values in a single paramter in Informatica Developer(IDQ) and later can read the values from parameter file

Tags: etl, informatica

Using this on source table query in mapping

BO_CLASS_CODE in '$p_class_cd'

BO_CLASS_CODE in ($p_class_cd)  --Tries this also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIxPp.png)

parameter used in mapping with string data type
$p_class_cd as business partner,base customer account
$p_class_cd as 'business partner','base customer account'--Tried this also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27sda.png)

Source side is getting validated but not able to pick the values as passed in paramter.I want to filter with multiple values like business partner,base customer account.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error occured with invalid sql query error.

Comment: My question is it possible even possible to pass multiple values in IDQ /Informatica Developer as its taking all the values as a single string

Comment: Create multiple parameter value for each string and pass it to the source

Comment: Can you give me an example I tried doing but again the src SQL query was not getting validated.

Comment: can you try change SQL  and add IN ($$param)   and then pass 'val1','val2','val3' as default values ?

Comment: My requirements changes with every project but the mapping remains same so there is no fixed number of values that I can use that no of paramters